# How to clear color for TopDrawable of Textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

In my application I change color of Top drawable of `Textview` using below code.

```
tvTopDrawable.setColorFilter("#E1BEE7", Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Now I want to clear this color from my drawable.
I have tried `tvTopDrawable.clearColorFilter();`

But it seems its not working sometime.

I used that same image in other `Activity` of my `Application`.

Where to write `clearColorFilter()` so it clears the color from drawable,Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting color filter to transparent 
`tvTopDrawable.setColorFilter("#00E1BEE7", Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: Hi ,I am setting dynamic color when i start activity. I want to remove that color..so when that image is used in other activity it doesn't have that color..

Comment: So maybe you could set the color as default from your xml file and from your activity change it with the filter as you already do.